# When exactly does this inequality hold/fail?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $\alpha, \beta, x, y \in [0, 1]$. And suppose that $y + \beta \leq 1$, $x + y \leq 1$, $x + \alpha\leq 1$. Then, can anyone tell me when exactly does the following inequality fail/hold?

$\alpha(1 - y- \beta) + \beta(1 - x) - xy \geq 0$

I've already figured out that $\beta \geq x$ is a sufficient condition for the inequality to hold. However, I've found both cases where it holds and where it fails for $\beta < x$. What are the missing conditions to characterise when the inequality holds/fails here?

Answer (score 1):

Denote the LHS of the inequality by $f$ where

$$f(x,y,\alpha,\beta)=\alpha(1-y)+\beta(1-x)-\alpha\beta-xy$$

Clearly $f$ is strictly decreasing in $x$ and $y$. When $x+y=1$, we have

$$f(x,1-x,\alpha,\beta)=(1-\alpha-x)(\beta-x).$$

Now, this quadratic has roots $\beta$ and $1-\alpha$, and so is nonnegative when $x\leq \min\{1-\alpha,\beta\}$ or when $x\geq \max\{1-\alpha ,\beta\}$.

The working above shows that the following sets of conditions are sufficient for nonnegativity of $f$

1. $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$ $x\in[0,\min\{1-\alpha,\beta\}]$, $y\geq 0$ $x+y\leq 1$
2. $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$ $x\geq\max\{1-\alpha ,\beta\}$, $y\geq 0$ $x+y\leq 1$

Note that you do not need the condition $y\leq 1-\beta$ as a separate condition in either case. However for the second set of conditions, $y\leq 1-\beta$, is implied by $x\geq \beta$ and $x+y\leq 1$.

Since $f(x,y,\alpha,\beta)=f(y,x,\beta,\alpha)$, by symmetry the following conditions are also sufficient

3. $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$ $x\geq 0$, $y\in[0,\min\{\alpha,1-\beta\}]$, $x+y\leq 1$
4. $\alpha,\beta\in[0,1]$ $x\geq 0$, $y\geq\max\{\alpha,1-\beta\}$, $x+y\leq 1$

Comment: Thanks so much. This is a very helpful answer.

Comment: I think there might be a mistake in here. In particular, I think that your expression for $f(x, 1-x, \alpha, \beta)$ is wrong, the $x^{2}$ term should be positive. It also seems that $x + y = 1$ and $x = 1 - \alpha$ dosen't violate the inequality, in fact it always validates it (with $f(x, 1-x, \alpha, \beta) = 0$).

Comment: See my edit. Fixing my mistake allows me to easily derive some sufficient conditions for nonnegativity (as long as I haven't made another stupid mistake!)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Makes more sense now. Do you have any more thoughts about how we can violate the inequality, in particular, for any value of $\beta$, can we always $x, y, \alpha$ such that the inequality is violated?

Comment: The working above shows that if $y=1-x$ (so that $f$ is minimized with respect to $y$) then the inequality does not hold if  $x$ is between $1-\alpha$ and $\beta$. The only way to rule this out is to make $1-\alpha=\beta$.

Comment: of course, thanks.